# Email Template using Zurb library not responsive in Firefox

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, html-email

```html
<table class="row">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td class="small-5 large-7 column">
          <p class="heading-text">ITEM</p>
        </td>
        <td class="small-3 large-2 columns space" align="center">
          <p class="heading-text text-center">QTY</p>
        </td>
        <td class="small-4 large-3 columns">
          <p class="heading-text text-right">TOTAL</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td class="small-5 large-7 columns space">
          <h6>1613 | <span class="memo-text">Out</span></h6>
          <p class="desc">The framework includes two typographic scalesone uses a narrow range of sizes.</p>
        </td>
        <td class="small-2 large-2 columns space" align="center">
          <h6 class="text-center">15.00</h6>
        </td>
        <td class="small-5 large-3 columns space" align="center">
          <h6 class="text-right">$394,567.00</h6>
          <p class="desc text-right">10.00%</p>
          <p class="desc text-right">$39,800.00</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

These two rows not displaying properly in mobile view in mozilla firefox. Last column `<p class="heading-text text-right">TOTAL</p>` move next row.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: What does the space class do?

Comment: mozilla version 41.0.2

Comment: .space{
    padding-bottom : 0px !important;
    margin-bottom : 0px !important;
    padding-left : 4px !important;
    padding-right : 4px !important;
  }

Comment: I use Zurb css file.

Comment: Which version of foundation-email are you using?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I added link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smu6o5yj/show/)

Answer (score 1):

This Foundation-emails issue with Firefox is still open, but can be fixed in this way:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 596px) {
  td.small-6, th.small-6 {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}
```

Thanks to [@ryanjavens](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-emails/issues/794)

To make it work with your structure, try as follows and tell me if you can solve it:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 596px) {
    td.small-6, th.small-6,
    td.small-5, th.small-5,
    td.small-4, th.small-4,
    td.small-3, th.small-3,
    td.small-2, th.small-2,
    td.small-1, th.small-1{
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}

.space {
    padding-bottom : 0px !important;
    margin-bottom :  0px !important;
    padding-left :   4px !important;
    padding-right :  4px !important;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" class="container float-center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>

        <table class="row">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="small-5 large-7 column">
                <p class="heading-text">ITEM</p>
              </td>
              <td class="small-3 large-2 columns space" align="center">
                <p class="heading-text text-center">QTY</p>
              </td>
              <td class="small-4 large-3 columns">
                <p class="heading-text text-right">TOTAL</p>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="small-5 large-7 columns space">
                <h6>1613 | <span class="memo-text">Out</span></h6>
                <p class="desc">The framework includes two typographic scalesone uses a narrow range of sizes.</p>
              </td>
              <td class="small-2 large-2 columns space" align="center">
                <h6 class="text-center">15.00</h6>
              </td>
              <td class="small-5 large-3 columns space" align="center">
                <h6 class="text-right">$394,567.00</h6>
                <p class="desc text-right">10.00%</p>
                <p class="desc text-right">$39,800.00</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

P.S. If you had to use other sizes, add them in the rule, for example to add `small-7`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 596px) {
    td.small-7, th.small-7,
    td.small-6, th.small-6,
    td.small-5, th.small-5,
    td.small-4, th.small-4,
    td.small-3, th.small-3,
    td.small-2, th.small-2,
    td.small-1, th.small-1 {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smu6o5yj/)

Comment: It working but still my problem not solved.  When I small the browser responsive not working. And horizontal scrollbar display in mozilla firefox.

Comment: hi @NishaPatel, I tried the code posted with Foundation for Emails 2.2.0 Sass version (I inserted only the html code above in `src/pages/index.html` and the css code in `src/assets/scss/app.scss`) and with Mozilla Firefox 58.0.1 (64 bit), Google Chrome 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64 bit) and Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18893; in all 3 browsers the columns do not break, the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear and passes correctly from small to large. Try the latest version of Foundation for Emails, maybe Sass.